# Approaches to minification and concatenation of app JS

Tags: javascript, performance, caching

I'm working on large JavaScript application and I'm tasked with making some improvements to the front end app performance. One hit the app takes is on initial page load and in the number of HTTP requests. The app I'm working on does not currently use any minification or concatenation.

Best practices suggest that it would be best minify and concat all of the application files into a single file. This would be the typical approach that I would take. In this case, there are other factors that I am trying to consider:

- Some dependencies are being cached for use across different apps like jQuery, jQuery UI, etc.
- Some dependencies are frequently updated and not subject to the same caching policies

The code loads dependencies in a rather nasty way. For context:

```
var loadDependencies = function (onFilesReadyCallback) {

var files = [
    [
        '/libs/cached/js/lib1.js', // Cached
        '/libs/cached/js/lib2.js', // Cached
        '/libs/cached/js/lib3.js', // Cached
        '/libs/js/lib4.js', // Not cached
        '/libs/cached/js/lib5.js', // Cached
        '/libs/cached/js/lib6.js', // Cached
        '/libs/cached/js/lib7.js', // Cached
        '/libs/js/lib8.js', // Not cached
        '/libs/cached/js/lib9.js', // Cached
        '/libs/js/lib10.js', // Not cached
    ],
    [
        '/libs/js/lib11.js', // Not cached
    ],
    [
        '/libs/cached/js/lib12.js', // Cached
    ]
];

var appScriptElement = document.querySelector('script[src*="app.js"]');

var loadFiles = function (files, onFilesLoaded) {
    var filesLoaded = 0;
    var filesCount = files.length;

    (function onTimer() {
        if (filesLoaded === filesCount) {
            if ('function' === typeof onFilesLoaded) {
                onFilesLoaded();
            }
            return;
        }

        window.setTimeout(onTimer, 50);
    })();

    for (var i = 0; i < filesCount; i++) {
        var filename = files[i];

        if (filename.indexOf('.js') > -1 && !document.querySelector('script[src*="' + filename + '"]')) {
            var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
            scriptElement.src = filename;
            scriptElement.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
                filesLoaded += 1;
            });
            appScriptElement.parentNode.appendChild(scriptElement, appScriptElement);
        } else {
            // Previously loaded this file
            filesLoaded += 1;
        }
    }
};

var onReady = function () {
    if ('function' === typeof onFilesReadyCallback) {
        onFilesReadyCallback();
    }
};

loadFiles(files[0], function () {
    loadFiles(files[1], function () {
        loadFiles(files[2], onReady);
    });
});
```

};

I'm going to change the loading strategy. My instinct is to concat and uglify all of the dependencies into a single JS with gulp/grunt, but I want need to consider that some of the resources are being cached. Would loading several cached dependencies be better than loading one single uncached app file? Does anyone have any thoughts or advice for loading JS files that have mixed caching policies?

Comment: it would probably load quicker if you simply hard-coded all the scripts into html tags for maximum browser optimization. you're only going to be saving a few hundred ms the first visit at best, so is that worth complicating your workflow or introducing un-needed complexity?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @dandavis. I should add that this approach might not work in my case. The app in question, is not a standalone app, it is shared across several other applications. Doing this would mean other app teams would need to maintain and monitor updates to any of the dependencies hardcoded in their view rather than a single app file.

Comment: ok, well you would do well to at least get rid of the timer part and use pure event-driven loading. if you really really must wait that long between bundles, you could at least load them all without executing right away, so that when your code adds them again as needed, they load and execute instantly. just flatten the array and use ajax to ping all the script urls to populate the http cache. that would ultimately be almost as fast as hard-coding. if they all come from a single domain, 2-4 medium-size bundles will typically outperform a single monolithic bundle due to pipelineing.